# why concatenated string classnames don't work in tailwind?

Tags: css, string, next.js, concatenation, tailwind-css

Everytime I end up using style attribute beside className because none of the examples below apply styles to my react elements.
Could you explain why this happens and how I can solve the issue?

I've read the docs (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names), but my use case is: user is choosing a color from color picker, then I change background according to that. I cannot pass "bg-[colorValue]" value to every single color, so I have to concatenate the value with "bg-[" afterwards.Because I cannot map all colors to full classnames.

```
const red500 = "red-500";
const red600Hex = "#dc2626";
const bgColor = "bg-[" + red600Hex + "]";
const bgColor2 = "bg-[" + "#dc2626" + "]";

function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <h1 className={` bg-${red500} `}>Hello</h1>
            <h1 className={` bg-[${red600Hex}] `}>Hello</h1>
            <h1 className={` bg-${`[${red600Hex}]`} `}>Hello</h1>
            <h1 className={` ${bgColor} `}>Hello</h1>
            <h1 className={` ${bgColor2} `}>Hello</h1>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: What's the rendered output?

Comment: i can see that correct classname is added to html element. but styles are not applied. so it never works

Comment: I don't think concatenation is your problem; it's problematic characters in your class names. For instance, `#`, `[`, and `]` are all allowed in class names, but must be escaped to be valid. See [Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/448981/215552) and especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6732899/215552)

Comment: the issue is not with it. I can pass bg-[#151515] to className attribute as it is. But when I pass concatenated string variable name, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You needn't worry about string concatenation when [Template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) strings work just fine:

```
const red500 = 'red-500';
const red600Hex = '#dc2626';
const bgColor = `bg-[${red600Hex}]`;
const bgColor2 = `bg-[${'#dc2626'}]`;

export function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1 className={` bg-${red500} `}>Hello</h1>
      <h1 className={` bg-[${red600Hex}] `}>Hello</h1>
      <h1 className={` bg-${`[${red600Hex}]`} `}>Hello</h1>
      <h1 className={` ${bgColor} `}>Hello</h1>
      <h1 className={` ${bgColor2} `}>Hello</h1>
    </>
  );
}
```

[Tailwind Playground](https://playcode.io/1535557)

The above link did also give me a warning about concatenation:
"Bug Finder: Unexpected string concatenation of literals.eslint"
[image: Warning message]

### Edit:

I even added an option to dynamically control the color of the last `h1` from state:

```
const colors = [
  {value: "#dc2626"},
  {value: "#dc06e6"},
  {value: "#dce606"},
]


export function App() {
  const [color, setColor] = React.useState(colors[0].value)
  return (
    <>
      <h1 className={`text-green-500 bg-${red500} `}>Hello</h1>
      <h1 className={`bg-[${red600Hex}] `}>Hello</h1>
      <h1 className={`text-green-200 bg-${`[${red600Hex}]`} `}>Hello</h1>
      <h1 className={`${bgColor} `}>Hello</h1>
      <h1 className={`bg-[${color}]`}>Hello</h1>
      <select onChange={(e) => setColor(e.currentTarget.value)}>
        {colors.map(c => <option className={`bg-[${c.value}]`} value={c.value}>{c.value}</option>)}
      </select>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Gif showing dynamically set color from Select]

Comment: It still doesnt work with template literals either.

Comment: In that case I think you have a different issue and need to share more code, because your code in the Playground link I shared works fine (event the string concatenation). So for it to not be working, there's got to be a different issue somewhere else...

Comment: Well, I've created my project with create-next-app and choose tw from cli when initializing. So there is nothing I changed in boilerplate next.js app.

Comment: Did you follow the next steps regarding [installation](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs#install-tailwind-via-npm) and [including the tailwind css](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs#include-tailwind-in-your-css)

Comment: Every tailwind code is working in my project actually. Except concatenated strings.

Comment: I've updated the playground to include data from state

Comment: I believe that playcode made some tweaks on how purgecss works to their tailwind react starter kit. Because even Tailwind docs says that dynamicly concatenated classnames will be ignored by purge and we should not try to do that. (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names) But that you for your effort trying to help. So yeah, my guess is that playcode did some hackings behind the scene, but I cannot be sure

Comment: have same issue, wondering what is the best solution to implement to create calssname using template literals...

Comment: Probably the same method, but the state class name would come from selecting from a list of options where the `value` would be the whole class name, rather than the contorted string in this answer (e.g. instead of `class={\`bg-[${stateVar}]\`}`, you could simply have the `class={stateVar}`)